# Fetching large volume of data from postgres db using spring boot rest api

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to fetch data using Spring Boot for my REST API from PostgreSQL Database, I have more than 30 million records in my database, the API takes a lot of time to pull data from the database and sometimes it results on time out error when trying to fetch data, I don't know what I'm missing on this implementation or it's the query that takes a lot of time and if is the query how best can I optimize it so as I can fast track the pulling of large volume of data more faster from the database and get the count depending on some conditions, I joining three tables each with more than 30+ million records.

Below is my code structure / implementation

// Below is my Interface Class

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, String> {

 @Query("select DISTINCT c, o from Client c left join Order o on c.ClientID = o.ClientID left join Status s on c.ClientID = s.ClientID where o.Code ='2' and "
            + "o.OrderDate >=:startDate and o.OrderDate <=:endDate and s.StatusDate >=:startDate and s.StatusDate <=:endDate and (s.OrderStatus != 'Cancelled' or s.OrderStatus != 'Pending')")
 List<Client> countClientOrder(LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate);
}
```

// Below is my service implementation class

```
@Service
public class ClientService {
    
    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;
    
    public int countClientOrder(int year, int month) {
        
    YearMonth yearMonth_ = YearMonth.of(year, month);
    LocalDate original_startDate = yearMonth_.atDay(1);
    LocalDate original_endDate = yearMonth_.atEndOfMonth();
    
    LocalDateTime startDate = original_startDate.atStartOfDay();
    LocalDateTime endDate = original_endDate.atStartOfDay();
    
    var data = clientRepository.countClientOrder(startDate, endDate).size();
    return data;
    }
}
```

// Below is my Rest API

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders_api")
public class ClientApi {

    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;
    
    @GetMapping("/requested_on/{year}/{month}")
    protected int getClient_Orders(@PathVariable int year, @PathVariable int month) {
    return clientService.countClientOrder(year,month);  
    }
}
```

// Client Model

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "tbl_clients")
public class Client {
    @Id
    private String ClientID;
    private String ClientNames;
    private String NickName;
    private String Gender;
    private String Country;
    private String Email;
    private String Phone;
    
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Order.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ClientID", referencedColumnName = "ClientID")
    private List<Order> order;
    
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Status.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ClientID", referencedColumnName = "ClientID")
    private List<Status> status;
}
```

// Orders Model

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "tbl_orders")
public class Order {
   @Id
   private String OrderId;
   private LocalDateTime OrderDate;
   private String OrderType;
   private String Code;
   private Int Quantity;
   private String OrderLocation;
   private String ClientID;
  
   @JsonIgnore
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "ClientID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private Client client;
}
```

// Status Model

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "tbl_status")
public class Status {
   @Id
   private String StatusId;
   private LocalDateTime StatusDate;
   private String OrderStatus;
   private String Notes;
   private String ClientID;
  
   @JsonIgnore
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "ClientID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
   private Client client;
}
```

Any Suggestions will be much appreciated just to speed up my rest api to pull data faster.

Comment: For starters don't use `@Data` with entities that is bad (https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/) and as you are using `DISTINCT` and have a large cartesian product due to your multiple joins this is a bad thing. Finally retrievintg your whole database, then marshalling it all to objects and then just doing a `size` on the result list is just dumb (sorry for not putting it more pollite). Just use a count on the database insetad of this.

Comment: Thanks so much @M.Deinum for quick response and do not worry about that dumb word  can you please provide some example on how I can you count on my query

Comment: THat is what SQL `SELECT COUNT ... ` is for and the same is available in JPQL, your query seems to be inspired by both anyway and I don't really get why you need the additional joins as JPA can figure that out itself.

Comment: So I should count the column that I want then adding the conditions without using left join is that correct if I get you clearly @M.Deinum?

Comment: No. You need the same query but use COUNT instead of selecting all your objects. Why select all the data, convert to objects when you only need the number of objects.

Comment: Thanks so much @M.Deinum for that suggestion I have changed the query to SELECT COUNT but still it takes much time although the time has reduced a little bit

Comment: Please show what you have done, and also the time difference.

Comment: count c, o from Client c left join Order o on c.ClientID = o.ClientID left join Status s on c.ClientID = s.ClientID where o.Code ='2' and "
            + "o.OrderDate >=:startDate and o.OrderDate <=:endDate and s.StatusDate >=:startDate and s.StatusDate <=:endDate and (s.OrderStatus != 'Cancelled' or s.OrderStatus != 'Pending')  it takes 7minutes to pull results from the database

Comment: You should have something like `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C) FROM Client c ... ` you are selecting 2 things A count and objects and then ditching the objects (the orders). So it is still pulling in additional data. And please add requested information to the question as the comments are totally unreadable.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment @M.Deinum that worked perfect! I really I apreciate it thanks a lot and stay blessed!